# Pandas: I can't solve this warning: SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using google colaboratory and following is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from fredapi import Fred # Api to import economic data

fred = Fred(api_key = 'my_api_key')

search_GDPperCapita = fred.search('gross domestic product per capita', order_by = 'popularity', filter = ('units', 'Current+U.S.+Dollars')) # This returns a dataframe of 238 rows × 15 columns. One of the columns is the 'id' column that contains codes for economic indicators.

new_df = search_GDPperCapita.loc[search_GDPperCapita['id'].str.match(pat = 'PCAGDP[A-Z][A-Z]A646NWDB')] #Filtering data based on the 'id' column

new_df['country'] = new_df['title'].str.extract('Gross Domestic Product Per Capita for (.+)') #Creating new column
```

When creating the column 'country in the new_df, the SettingWithCopyWarning is raised.

I was supposed that using 'loc' solved the problem, but It didn't.

Please give some guidance.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `new_df = search_GDPperCapita.loc[search_GDPperCapita['id'].str.match(pat = 'PCAGDP[A-Z][A-Z]A646NWDB')].copy()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)